# how to set an event callback for a domain lifecycle

Tags: c++, qt, libvirt

I'm following [this](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html) document and I'm using qt to implement this event

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <libvirt/libvirt.h>

void
domainLifecycleCb(virConnectPtr conn,
                  virDomainPtr dom,
                  void * opaque)
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    virEventRegisterDefaultImpl();
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    virConnectPtr conn = virConnectOpen("qemu:///session");
    virDomainPtr domain = virDomainLookupByName(conn, "Windows");

    qDebug() << virConnectDomainEventRegisterAny(conn,
                                                 domain,
                                                 VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_ID_LIFECYCLE,
                                                 VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_CALLBACK(domainLifecycleCb),
                                                 NULL, NULL);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I tried different methods but the event doesn't work when the domain gets shutdown or started.

By that I mean the callback function should get call when the domain life-cycle changes, And I'm determining that by showing an output in the callback function.

Comment: Why did you tag this C? QT generally uses C++.

Comment: Maybe you could edit question and define "the event doesn't work".

Comment: @kebs, The callback function doesn't show the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function that needs to be called in a loop to keep the connection alive

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <libvirt/libvirt.h>
#include <QThread>

void domainLifecycleCb(virConnectPtr conn,
                  virDomainPtr dom,
                  void * opaque)
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    virEventRegisterDefaultImpl();
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    virConnectPtr conn = virConnectOpen("qemu:///session");
    virDomainPtr domain = virDomainLookupByName(conn, "WindowsECO");

    QThread *thread = QThread::create([]{
        while (true) {
            qDebug() << virEventRunDefaultImpl();
        } });
    thread->start();

    qDebug() << virConnectDomainEventRegisterAny(conn,
                                                 domain,
                                                 VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_ID_LIFECYCLE,
                                                 VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_CALLBACK(domainLifecycleCb),
                                                 NULL, NULL);
    return a.exec();
}
```